# Deleting multiple lines based on serach conditon python

Tags: python

I am working on a DHCP editor to add, delete and search for a host. I have code that will search and add a host I figured I would somehow combine the two to delete a host and that did not work. What I would like to do is create a list of the element index of `f.readlines()`, then use values of myindex to and then run `lines.remove(myindex)` from the DHCP file I am editing.

example I would like to search for `foonode` or any node and remove the following format:

```
    host barnode{
    option host-name "barnode";
    option root-path "0.0.0.0:/barnode";
    option subnet-mask ;
    option routers ;
    hardware ethernet  ;
    fixed-address ;
}





host foonode{
    option host-name "foonode";
    option root-path "0.0.0.0:/foonode";
    option subnet-mask ;
    option routers ;
    hardware ethernet  ;
    fixed-address ;
}




host foobarnode{
    option host-name "foobarnode";
    option root-path "0.0.0.0:/foobarnode";
    option subnet-mask ;
    option routers ;
    hardware ethernet ;
    fixed-address ;
}
```

I can search the file using the following code:

```
def delete_host():

    host=raw_input('Please enter host you would like to delete: ');
    start = False;
    f=open(infile, 'r')
    myfile=str()
    myindex=list()
    mystr=str()
    count = 0
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
            if re.search(host, line):
                    start = True

            if start:
                   print line
                   myindex = [lines.index(line)]   


                    if re.search('}', line):
                            break
```

and get this output:

```
    host foonode{

    option host-name "foonode";

    option root-path "0.0.0.0:/foonode";

    option subnet-mask ;

    option routers ;

    hardware ethernet ;

    fixed-address ;
```

I wanted to create and index list for the element index values for the `f.readlines()` in the search conditions. Then use those values to do a `lines.remove(myindex.index())` to remove the output I get when running the above code. Basically how do I search for any node and delete them from the file. 
Maybe creating an index is not the best way to approach this problem I am just running out of expressions to search for in google.

I know I will have to do `newfile= open('/var/tmp/foodhcp' 'w')` but I want to get the logic correct before I start writing files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same issue I finally solved the problem. Talk about the KISS principle in action. Thank to everyone who responded. The following code will remove a host anywhere a dhcpd.conf file if search condition is true.

```
    def delete_host():

        host=raw_input('Please enter host you would like to delete: ');
        start = False;
        infile= '/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf'
        f=open(infile, 'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        nf = open('/var/tmp/testing','w')

        for line in lines:
                if re.search(host, line):
                        print 'if search'
                        start = True
                if start:
                        print 'is start'
                        print line
                        if re.search('}', line):
                                start = False
                                print 'false'
                else:

                        nf.write(line)
                        print 'writing'


delete_host()
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that deleting items from a list you are looping over won't work the way you might expect. I suggest

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
del a[2:4]
```

a == [1, 2, 5]

You are already able to find the start and end lines, so just run del after you find those.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the list of lines, just create a new updated list from the parts before and after the lines to be removed:

```
import re

with open('data.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()

print("Before:")
print(s)

def delete_host(s):
    host = raw_input('Please enter host you would like to delete: ')

    lines = s.split('\n')
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if re.match(r'\s*host\s+' + host + '\s*{', line):
            break

    for j, line in enumerate(lines[i+1:]):
        if re.match(r'\s*}', line):
            break

    j = i + j + 1

    new_lines = lines[:i] + lines[j+1:]
    return '\n'.join(new_lines)

s = delete_host(s)
print("After:")
print(s)
```

(note that there is no error checking for a missing hostname, or for an incorrect format, or for hostnames with funny symbols that can interfere with regexps).

If you are certain that all the entries always look like you described (in particular, `}` will not be encountered anywhere in the `host` body), you can simplify it to

```
def delete_host(s):
    host = raw_input('Please enter host you would like to delete: ')
    return re.sub(r'\s*host\s+' + host + '\s*{[^}]*}', '', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

The safest way would be to actually parse the config file, get a data structure, remove the entry, and then create a new config file.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty I did not understand the examples above. I kept chugging along and came up with the following, I created a list populated with the output of my search code. I then want to write every line that is not equal to myindex. I am confused

```
import re
infile='C:\dhcp.txt'
def delete_host():
    infile = 'C:\dhcp.txt'
    host=raw_input('Please enter host you would like to delete: ');
    start = False;
    f=open(infile, 'r')
    nf=open(r'C:\test.txt', 'w')
    myindex=list()
    mystr=str()
    count = 0
    lines = f.readlines()

    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if re.search(host, line):
                start = True
                if start:
                 myindex.append(line)
                if re.search('}',line):
                    break
    for myindex in lines:
        if lines != myindex:
            mystr.join(lines)
            nf.write(mystr)
            nf.close
delete_host();
```

I also tried creating a list of elements then trying to use del to remove those elements but I keep running into an error

```
def delete_host():
    infile = 'C:\dhcp.txt'
    host=raw_input('Please enter host you would like to delete: ');
    start = False;
    f=open(infile, 'r')
    nf=open(r'C:\test.txt', 'w')
    myfile=str()
    myindex=list()
    mystr=str()
    count = 0
    lines = f.readlines()

    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if re.search(host, line):
                start = True

            if start:

                #print line
                #myindex=lines.index(line)

                myindex.append(lines.index(line))
                #myindex.append(line)
                if re.search('}',line):
                    break
    print myindex
    print type(myindex[0])

    del lines[myindex]

delete_host();
```

error I get

```
Please enter host you would like to delete: rest
[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 7]
<type 'int'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\delete.py", line 52, in <module>
    delete_host();
  File "C:\delete.py", line 35, in delete_host
    del lines[myindex]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

but type returns int so I don't understand what I am doing.